# Проверка root прав Android

Tags: android, права, root

Возникла необходимость перед запуском приложения проверять наличие root прав на устройстве. При их отсутствии не запускать приложение. Оно просто работает до определенного события (нажатия на кнопку) только тогда запрашивает разрешение, а не при старте. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Методов много, самый железобетонный:

```
boolean isRoot=canExecuteCommand("/system/xbin/which su")
        || canExecuteCommand("/system/bin/which su") || canExecuteCommand("which su");

private static boolean canExecuteCommand(String command) {
    try {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
      return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: не подскажите, какой смысл перебирать пути, ведь по идее  достаточно было бы использовать только "which su"?

Comment: просто `which su` может дать ложный результат, если положить в `home` какую нить дурацкую заглушку с именем `su`

Comment: спасибо, идея понятна, хоть по моему приведенный выше код все равно сработает на "заглушку" в home